# Publishing using UniversalPackage@0 Task in Azure dev ops succeeds without error but package is not present in artifact feed

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

It appears as if the Azure dev ops pipeline successfully completes publishing the universal package with the UniversalPackage@0 task defined in my pipeline.yml file

```
# Publish Universal Package
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/release'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'SME/P3'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: 'sme-p3'
    versionOption: 'patch'
    packagePublishDescription: 'sme p3 files'
```

However when I look in the artifact-feed I don't see anything. What can be the reason for this? I'm able to publish this package using azure client on my windows machine but would really like to publish it via a pipeline. Any ideas what could be going on?

```
Starting: Universal publish
==============================================================================
Task         : Universal packages
Description  : Download or publish Universal Packages
Version      : 0.169.2
Author       : Microsoft Corporation
Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks
==============================================================================
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
Downloading: https://0t3vsblobprodcus362.vsblob.vsassets.io/artifacttool/artifacttool-win10-x64-Release_0.2.128.zip?sv=2019-02-02&sr=b&sig=OJQlTNqKnAnKymyuriGCGvAYbuhweqLb9skkk60PA0E%3D&spr=https&se=2020-06-18T15%3A13%3A48Z&sp=r&P1=1592492928&P2=11&P3=2&P4=aTtfv%2fhXIBUtlTO2nwePgROhTGvaZoMqq3eF7CPCwTs%3d
Caching tool: ArtifactTool 0.2.128 x64
SYSTEMVSSCONNECTION exists true
Finishing: Universal publish
```

Comment: Have you confirmed that `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/release` contains the files you want to publish? The most likely scenario is that nothing is showing up because you're not publishing any files. Did you try running with `system.debug` set to `true`?

Comment: Yes, the $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/release contains the files I want to publish. I ran with system.debug set to true. I got the following logs
`
2020-06-22T17:39:33.2912819Z ##[debug]Created webApi client for https://feeds.dev.azure.com/my-org/; options: {"proxy":null,"allowRetries":true,"maxRetries":5,"ignoreSslError":false}
2020-06-22T17:39:34.7959115Z ##[section]Finishing: Universal publish
`

Answer (score 0):

There is no publish in the log, so you won't see the package. There are two things need to be noticed:

1. `publishDirectory` doesn't support format `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/release`, you can publish files in `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/release` to `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)`, and then use `$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)` in `publishDirectory`: `publishDirectory: '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)'`
2. Check whether feed `P3` in team project `SME`, and make sure feed `P3` in Project scoped feeds.

[image]

---

Update:

Share my whole YAML file for your reference:

```
trigger:
- master

pool:
  vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'

variables:
  solution: '**/*.sln'
  buildPlatform: 'Any CPU'
  buildConfiguration: 'Release'

steps:
- task: UniversalPackages@0
  displayName: 'Universal publish'
  inputs:
    command: 'publish'
    publishDirectory: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)'
    feedsToUsePublish: 'internal'
    vstsFeedPublish: 'projectName/feedName'
    vstsFeedPackagePublish: packageName
    versionOption: 'patch'
    packagePublishDescription: test
```

Comment: Thank you. I checked that the feed appears under project-scoped feeds. Also even if I change to copy the files to '$(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)' and adjust the publishDirectory as suggested, I still don't see the files in the feed.

Comment: That's wired. Which build agent do you use? Could you try to create another feed and have another try?

Comment: I'm able to publish to feed via twine for a pip package wheel that I create in the pipeline. However in the same pipeline the UniversalPublish to the feed fails to upload any files and reports that it completed successfully. I think this is a bug in the software. I'm using a microsoft-hosted agent 'vs2017-win2016' to build

Comment: I've shared my whole YAML file in my post, which worked great on my side. Could you try to create a new feed in Artifact tab and have another try?

Comment: How's your issue going? How's the result if you create a new feed in a new team project? In addition, to publish to an Azure Artifacts feed, make sure you have set the `Project Collection Build Service` identity to be a `Contributor` on the feed.

Comment: The Project CollectionBuild Service is set to contributor. I’ve decided to file this as a bug with azure devops

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce your issue on my side, are you also able to reproduce this issue in a new created feed in other team project?